# What is the most popular way to define a background service in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, quartz.net, hangfire, background-service

I want to define a background service to update the status of database records daily. I've searched online and found multiple ways to do so like IHostedService, BackgroundService, Hangfire and Quartz.

I want a solution that can help me in the long run to define more background tasks that might include sending emails and notifications and updating things regularly.

So what is the most popular and used way to define a background service in ASP.NET Core, and what the pros and cons of each method?

Comment: You don't need any dependencies like Quartz, or any external services - it's straightforward to run a set-up a job-queue with `Channel<T>`, a `while()` loop, and `Task.Run` that you kick-off inside `Program.Main`. But ideally you'd use MS's `class BackgroundService : IHostedService` as a starting point.

Comment: @Dai but what about features that libraries like Hangfire offer, such as retries, persistence, and a monitoring dashboard?